# Amcharts 5 bar Chart Race - valueAxis (reset on chart replay)

Tags: amcharts5

This is a long shot - I modified the off-the-shelf amcharts 5 bar chart (race) - among other things, I added a pause/play button that includes a replay option to restart the chart from the first year.

The restart function works fine, except that:

- the valueAxis (xAxis) is continuously updated for each year with the max value for that year.
- the valueAxis maintains a highwater mark (of the highest value in any year).
- when I restart the chart, it doesn't reset the valueAxis to its original first year value, which  makes the chart look a bit odd (the columns for each category are compressed).

From the amcharts doc, I'm pretty sure this is all automatically maintained (and maybe one reason their sample race chart does not include a replay option).

Here's what the first year looks like (original): https://imtanuki.tinytake.com/msc/NzA5NDA4MV8xOTg0MjE5OQ

Here's what the first year looks like (after a restart):https://imtanuki.tinytake.com/msc/NzA5NDA4Ml8xOTg0MjIwMA

My question - is there any way to track the first year valueAxis max value and reset the valueAxis to that value on a restart?

There's a lot of code here, so just the salient parts...

Main Logic (play/pause/replay)

```
        function initEventListenerPlayButton () {
        playButton.events.on ( "click", function ( event ) {
                switch ( chartState.state ) {
                    case "NOT STARTED":
                        togglePlayButtonUpdate ("PLAYING", "PAUSE")
                        yearCurrent = yearMin;
                        // recalibrate xAxis
                        togglePlayButtonPlay ();
                        togglePlayButtonSort ();
                        break;
                    case "PAUSED":
                        togglePlayButtonUpdate ("PLAYING", "PAUSE")
                        togglePlayButtonPlay ();
                        togglePlayButtonSort ();
                        break;
                    case "PLAYING":
                        togglePlayButtonUpdate ("PAUSED", "PLAY")
                        togglePlayButtonPause ();
                        break;
                    default:
                    // nothing
                }
            }
        )
    }
```

Series Logic (where I think the valueAxis is updated)

```
        function initAmchartSeries () {
        // init series
        // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/series/
        let series = chart.series.push ( am5xy.ColumnSeries.new ( root, {
            xAxis: xAxis,
            yAxis: yAxis,
            valueXField: "value",
            categoryYField: "categoryItem"
        } ) );

        // init column border radius - top and bottom right
        series.columns.template.setAll ( {
            height: am5.percent ( 90 ),
            cornerRadiusBR: 4,
            cornerRadiusTR: 4
        } );

        //init column column colors
        series.columns.template.adapters.add ( "fill", function ( fill, target ) {
            return chart.get ( "colors" ).getIndex ( series.columns.indexOf ( target ) );
        } );

        // column stroke color - don't use chart colors
        //  series.columns.template.adapters.add ( "stroke", function ( stroke, target ) {
        //  return chart.get ( "colors" ).getIndex ( series.columns.indexOf ( target ) );
        // } );

        // column stroke color - override
        series.columns.template.adapters.add ( "stroke", () => {
            return am5.color ( 0x0060AF );
        } );

        // column stroke width and opacity - override
        series.columns.template.adapters.add ( "strokeWidth", () => {
            return 1;
        } );

        series.columns.template.adapters.add ( "strokeWeight", () => {
            return 100;
        } );

        // init label bullet
        series.bullets.push ( function () {
            return am5.Bullet.new ( root, {
                locationX: 1,
                sprite: am5.Label.new ( root, {
                    text: "{valueXWorking.formatNumber('#.# a')}",
                    fill: root.interfaceColors.get ( "alternativeText" ),
                    centerX: am5.p100,
                    centerY: am5.p50,
                    populateText: true
                } )
            } );
        } );

        return series;
    }
```

Update Logic (for each year)

```
        function updateData () {
        var itemsWithNonZero = 0;

        if ( dataYears[ yearCurrent ] ) {
            label.set ( "text", yearCurrent.toString () );

            am5.array.each ( series.dataItems, function ( dataItem ) {
                var category = dataItem.get ( "categoryY" );
                var value = dataYears[ yearCurrent ][ category ];

                if ( value > 0 ) {
                    itemsWithNonZero ++;
                }

                dataItem.animate ( {
                    key: "valueX",
                    to: value,
                    duration: stepDuration,
                    easing: am5.ease.linear
                } );
                dataItem.animate ( {
                    key: "valueXWorking",
                    to: value,
                    duration: stepDuration,
                    easing: am5.ease.linear
                } );
            } );

            yAxis.zoom ( 0, itemsWithNonZero / yAxis.dataItems.length );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works - it will reset the series and the x-axis, so that the chart will redisplay exactly the same each time it's replayed.

```
        function togglePlayButtonReInit () {
        // recalibrate xAxis
        chart.yAxes.removeIndex ( chart.yAxes.indexOf ( yAxis ) );
        chart.xAxes.removeIndex ( chart.xAxes.indexOf ( xAxis ) );
        chart.series.removeIndex ( chart.series.indexOf ( series ) );
        yAxis = initAmchartYAxis ();
        xAxis = initAmchartXAxis ();
        series = initAmchartSeries ();
        setInitialData ();
    }
```